# Adjust/control image src height on android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following code.
**triangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="-50%" 
            >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"  >
                 <solid
                    android:color="@color/gray" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And I used this triangle as a background for the below imageView.

```
  <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/you_tube"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/triangle" />
```

I have got the below image. This working fine.  [image]

Now, I want to reduce the height of the triangle. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to reduce the height of the triangle just increase `android:pivotX` value.

for example in your `shape.xml` file change from `android:pivotX="100%"` to `android:pivotX="120%"`

Comment: Thank you sir! Its works fine. Though I have tried another way to solve it. I have added `<stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="20dp"/>` inside `<shape>` tag.